# C++ What's wrong with this class?

Tags: c++, debugging, class

It doesn't compile in Visual Studio, it says

`1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup`
`1>position.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Position
{
private:
    int row;
    int column;
public:
    Position();         //constructor
    ~Position();        //destructor
    void setPos(int, int);  //set the position
    int getRow();       //return the current row
    int getColumn();    //return the current column
    void getPos();      //print the pos
    bool compare(int, int); //compare a row and column with the one in the class
};

Position::Position()
{}
Position::~Position()
{}
void Position::setPos(int x, int y)
{
    row = x;
    column = y;
}
int Position::getRow()
{
    return row;
}
int Position::getColumn()
{
    return column;
}
void Position::getPos()
{
    cout << "Row: " << row << "Column: " << column;
}
bool Position::compare(int x, int y)
{
    if(x == row && y == column)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check your compiler settings. Maybe it's expecting `_tmain()` or some MS-specific nonsense.

Comment: Also check if it expects argc and argv params to your main method

Comment: What sort of project did you create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compiled for me under Visual Studio Professional 2008.

Try creating a new project.

Select File->New and specify Project Type of Visual C++ -> Win32 -> Win32 Console Application.

Then click Ok.

Then click on Application Settings and uncheck "Precompiled header".

Then paste in your code and compile it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're creating an empty project or a Win32 *console* application. If you make a Win32 *Windows* application then you will get this error.

Comment: No, you'd get a very similar error that `WinMain` is not found.

Comment: @BenVoigt It doesn't occur that way for me. It worked perfectly with an empty project and with a console application. In fact, the error with Win32 Windows Application was *exactly* the same as he described.